# wxTaskBar with radioitems

Tags: c++, radio-button, wxwidgets, system-tray

I'm trying to implement a language choice submenu (radioitems) in the system tray menu using wxWidgets 2.8.12. But when I try to check the active language the item is still unchecked. Here is a piece of code from TrayIcon::CreatePopUpMenu()

```
info = locale->FindLanguageInfo(languages[i]);  //  languages - array of strings
wxMenuItem *item = menuLanguage->AppendRadioItem(ID_Locale + info->Language, info->Description);
if (locale->GetLanguage() == (item->GetId() - ID_Locale)))
      item->Check(true);
```

Events:

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(SystemTrayIcon, wxTaskBarIcon)
      EVT_MENU_RANGE(ID_Locale, ID_Locale + LANGUAGES_COUNT, TrayIcon::ChangeAppLocale)
      EVT_UPDATE_UI_RANGE(ID_Locale, ID_Locale + LANGUAGES_COUNT, TrayIcon::UISelectLocale)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

Action:

```
void TrayIcon::OnMenuUILocaleChange(wxUpdateUIEvent &event)
{
    int id = locale->GetLanguage();
    if (id == (event.GetId() - ID_Locale))
    {
        event.Check(true);
    }
}
```

So when I click on a radioitem the actions defined in TrayIcon::ChangeAppLocale are performed but the button is unchecked when I'm creating the menu. During the debugging I can see that item->Check(true) takes place and item->Checkable() becomes true. But later in the TrayIcon::OnMenuUILocaleChange the item is unchecked (I know it's a bit of doubleworking here but at least I can watch the check value)

When The same actions for the app menu (adding language submenu) are performed the check is active.

I have seen [Popup menu radio item checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631580/popup-menu-radio-item-checks) but the advices from there didn't help. Thank you

Comment: Also have tried checking after appending - still not working

Comment: Update: I'm able to change any checkitems in the tray menu but unable to change radioitems

Comment: This looks like a wxWidgets bug. If you can reproduce it with 3.0.1, please open a ticket on [wxTrac](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/), ideally with a minimal patch to the taskbar sample.